# System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found New

Tags: apex, visualforce, batch

```
 String emailBlastQuery = 'SELECT Id, Inquiry_Type__c, Product_type__c, Solution__c, Reason_For_Calling__c, '+
                                'Problem_Category__c, Duplicate_Case_Problem_Category__c,Duplicate_Case_Product_Type__c, '+
                                'Duplicate_Case_Reason_For_Calling__c, Duplicate_Case_Status__c,Web_Product_Business_Group__c, '+
                                'WebProductPLTypeName__c,Age_Hours__c,Language__c, Case_Status__c,Completed_Date__c, '+
                                'status__c, No_Of_Emails_Sent__c, No_Of_Duplicate_Cases__c '+
                                'FROM  Email_Blast__c '+
                                'WHERE status__c = '+System.Label.Email_Blast_Process_Status+
                                ' AND Criteria_Tested__c = ' + System.Label.Email_Blast_TestingStatus +
                                ' AND No_Of_Records_Satisfying_Criteria__c > '+System.Label.Email_Blast_Case_Count_Limit;

 System.debug('hello'+emailBlastQuery);
 return Database.getQueryLocator(emailBlastQuery);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems quite likely that the value of `System.Label.Email_Blast_Process_Status` is `New`. When building a dynamic query, you must wrap string values in escaped single quotes. You should also escape the `Label` itself.

```
'WHERE Field__c = \' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(Label.MyLabel) + ''\'
```

However, you don't even need to use a dynamic query here, so you should not. Always prefer a static query where one will work.

```
Database.query([
    SELECT ...
    FROM MyObject__c
    WHERE Field__c = :Label.MyLabel
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, in cases where dynamic SOQL is necessary, the `:` binding prefix still can be used but is limited to simple values (no `.` or method invocations). So taking Adrian's example this could be done:

```
String myLabel = Label.MyLabel;

'WHERE Field__c = :myLabel'
```

with the advantage that the various data types are handled correctly automatically, that the code is easier to read and that the [SOQL injection risk](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/secdev_injection_vulnerabilities/secdev_inject_prevent_soql_injection_) is automatically addressed.

But as Adrian recommends, always go for static SOQL if you can as:

- The query is easier to read - no quotes needed - and can be broken up over multiple lines to help with that readability without having to add string concatenation noise
- The compiler will check the syntax of the query and that the field and object names are correct (rather than you having to wait for a runtime error when you try the code)
- The `:` binding supports complex expressions (`.` and methods invocations)

I would write the query like this:

```
return [
    SELECT
        Id,
        Inquiry_Type__c,
        Product_type__c,
        Solution__c,
        Reason_For_Calling__c,
        Problem_Category__c,
        Duplicate_Case_Problem_Category__c,
        Duplicate_Case_Product_Type__c,
        Duplicate_Case_Reason_For_Calling__c,
        Duplicate_Case_Status__c,
        Web_Product_Business_Group__c,
        WebProductPLTypeName__c,
        Age_Hours__c,
        Language__c,
        Case_Status__c,
        Completed_Date__c,
        status__c,
        No_Of_Emails_Sent__c,
        No_Of_Duplicate_Cases__c
    FROM Email_Blast__c
    WHERE status__c = :Label.Email_Blast_Process_Status
    AND Criteria_Tested__c = :Label.Email_Blast_TestingStatus
    AND No_Of_Records_Satisfying_Criteria__c > :Label.Email_Blast_Case_Count_Limit
];
```